# Add to path helper for phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I want to be able to add a link

```
<%= link "Management", to: management_path(@conn, :management_dashboard) %>
```

However it doesn't seem like `:management_dashboard` is recognized
the error says

```
The following actions/clauses are supported:
management_path(conn_or_endpoint, :create, , opts \\ [])
management_path(conn_or_endpoint, :delete, id, opts \\ [])
management_path(conn_or_endpoint, :index, , opts \\ [])
management_path(conn_or_endpoint, :show, id, opts \\ [])
management_path(conn_or_endpoint, :update, id, opts \\ [])
```

My question is how do I make it so that :management_dashboard is recognized in the path helper?
I already have a function in the controller

```
def management_dashboard(conn, _params) do
    render(conn, "some_page.html")
end
```

I want to be able to put the :management_dashboard inside my `ManagementController`
Doing `get("/managements/management_dashboard", ManagementController, :management_dashboard)`
gives me an error that for some reason traces back to the :show function in `ManagementController`

Edit: added more information

Comment: You need to add the route for that action.
`get "/dashboard", YourApp.ManagementDashboardController, :management_dashboard`

Comment: I want to put the :management_dashboard function into the ManagementController

and doing
`get("/managements/management_dashboard", ManagementController, :management_dashboard)`

gives me an error

`deps/ecto/lib/ecto/repo/queryable.ex:348: value `"management_dashboard"` in `where` cannot be cast to type :id in query:`

Comment: Please add the _complete_ error message to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The path helper functions are created for routes. when you use `page_path(@conn, :index)` it is actually `HelloWeb.Router.Helpers.page_path(Conn, :index)`.

So you need to define the route in the router before you accessing the path helper

add the following in your router file.

```
get "/dashboard", ManagementDashboardController, :management_dashboard
```